# Running Spring Boot with Apache Storm 1.2.1 initialization exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, apache-storm

I run Spring Boot project which includes Apache Storm dependency. Everything was right when I used Apache Storm 0.9.3v. When I upgraded it to the latest one (1.2.1v), I got next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: getConfiguration for class org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:315) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$get_logger_levels.invoke(worker.clj:499) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5545$exec_fn__1369__auto__$reify__5547.run(worker.clj:748) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5545$exec_fn__1369__auto____5546.invoke(worker.clj:624) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5545$mk_worker__5636.doInvoke(worker.clj:598) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:409) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalContainer.launch(LocalContainer.java:61) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalContainerLauncher.launchContainer(LocalContainerLauncher.java:45) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.handleWaitingForBlobLocalization(Slot.java:387) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.stateMachineStep(Slot.java:275) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.run(Slot.java:752) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]

2018-05-04 16:25:22.193 ERROR 4478 --- [      SLOT_1027] org.apache.storm.util                    : Halting process: ("Error on initialization")

java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
    at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5545$mk_worker__5636.doInvoke(worker.clj:598) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:409) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalContainer.launch(LocalContainer.java:61) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalContainerLauncher.launchContainer(LocalContainerLauncher.java:45) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.handleWaitingForBlobLocalization(Slot.java:387) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.stateMachineStep(Slot.java:275) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.run(Slot.java:752) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
```

Comment: Solved. I had multiple log4j-slf4j bindings. Excluding one of them solved the issue.

Comment: Would you care to share the gradle config to exclude the dependency ? I am trying to use Spring Boot and Storm and EXLUDED log4j-sfl4j-impl from Storm compile in gradle dependencies BUT now I'm getting the error you've reported  above ..

Comment: I used maven instead of Gradle